# SP online is it still possible to import a modified CQWP?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part

I have been doing this since some months ago.

Export the CQWP and adding some fields in the property `name="CommonViewFields"`

When importing I get:

> The file you imported is not valid. Verify that the file is a Web Part description file (`*.webpart or *.dwp`) and that it contains well-formed XML.

Has something changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out why

I did not remove the / from this line

Answer (score 0):

What fields did you add in the property CommonViewFields. Per my test, it works on my end.

Here is what I did:

1. Export the Content Query Web Part.
2. Change the property CommonViewFields to this:
   [image]
3. Go to Web Part Gallery `/wp/Forms/AllItems.aspx` , upload the .webpart file.
   [image]

Comment: I add things like >company, text; Date, DateTime<

Comment: It's  not supported to add these things. The property element only has three attributes: name, type, and null. The name and type attributes are required; null is used only if the property has a null value. Please read this:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms227561(v=vs.140)

Comment: I do not think you have understood where is this line. The link you have provided is about another thing. In this guide if you look below point 3, that is the place I am working on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms497457%28v%3Doffice.14%29

Comment: Sorry to misunderstand that. You could try to upload the .webpart file to the Web Part Gallery. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/270604/sp-online-is-it-still-possible-to-import-a-modified-cqwp